# Developing web parts on SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I am trying SharePoint web part development for the first time with SharePoint 2010. I have SharePoint 2010 installed on a server and I want to start web part development on other systems. But when I tried to create a web part project on that system it says:

"A SharePoint server is not installed on this computer. A SharePoint server must be installed to work with SharePoint projects."

Please can anyone tell me how can I proceed with web part development.

Is it really necessary to install SharePoint server on each development system where we want to develop SharePoint web parts?

I think there could be a way to install SharePoint on a server and connect all development systems to that server and develop web parts on them.

Please help me if any one knows a solution to this problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You must need to install a sharepoint server in environment where you wanted to develop sharepoint webpart. other wise, do remote destop to server system and develop sharepoint webpart over there.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly develop web parts on a system without SharePoint installed. Although, it is a *lot* easier to do it with SharePoint. I typically develop in a virtual machine (I use VMware Workstation) with SharePoint and development tools installed. This gives you an environment to develop directly to a SharePoint environment and the VM gives you simple snapshot capability.

If you want to develop without SharePoint, look at using something like [WSPBuilder](http://wspbuilder.codeplex.com/) instead of the Visual Studio SharePoint projects (which require connectivity). You'll also need to make a local copy of some of the SharePoint assemblies to reference in your project.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the tools for SharePoint 2010 development in Visual Studio 2010 you have to have SharePoint installed locally.

You can do SharePoint development without using these tools, the process is described in [Chapter 2 of Inside Windows SharePoint Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798298.aspx)